# When the Service Base Filtering Engine is active, ping and Remote Dsktvp do not work

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, ping

In a Windows Server 2008 R2

When the Service Base Filtering Engine (BFE) 
Running is a Ping and RDP are disabled and do not work.

But when I disable the service is 
Both Ping and RDP work.

What do I need to do to make the Base Filtering Engine (BFE) work with both Ping and Rdp.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Windows Firewall rules to allow ICMP and TCP port 3389 inbound.

The Windows Firewall is built on top of the Base Filtering Engine, and as such, depends on it. So when you turn off BFE, Windows Firewall dies as well.  When you enable BFE, Windows Firewall works. When Windows Firewall works, it blocks incoming traffic unless you have turned on rules to allow the traffic in.